# fgets or strtok error returning unwanted third line

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I had the following code to try and get 2 values for 2 different players, however this code is causing an unwanted third line to appear as shown below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    printf("Player %c>", player);
    fgets(move, 4, stdin);
    y_coord = strtok(move, sp);
    x_coord = strtok(NULL, sp);


    printf("You entered: %s, %s\n", x_coord, y_coord);
    if(player == 'O'){
        player = 'X';
    }
    else{
        player = 'O';
    }
}
```

output:

```
Player O>5 5
You entered: 5, 5
Player X>You entered: (null),

Player O>^C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you read only three characters, which leaves the newline in the input buffer.

The size passed to [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) must include the terminating `'\0'` character, so to have `fgets` read the newline as well you need a buffer size of `5` character, i.e.

```
char move[5];  // Two characters separated by space, plus newline and terminator
...
fgets(move, sizeof(move), stdin);
```

Comment: that works but now it copies in a \n as well. any ways to remove that?

Comment: @Altern8 Yes there are ways to remove it. If it exists in the string, it will always be a position `strlen(move) - 1`. Check for it there. Also remember that a good way to remove the last character is to change it to the terminator character `'\0'`.

Comment: @Altern8 See [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359)

Comment: Checking `strlen(move) - 1` sets up for an exploit - rare, but `move[0]` may be 0.